# PHP Fatal error: Class 'WC_Shipping_Method' not found in custom class addon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a shipping method addon to WooCommerce: http://pastebin.com/SCsbDnnn

However, it doesn't work and gives this output: PHP Fatal error:

```
 Class 'WC_Shipping_Method' not found in class-wc-shipping-per-product.php, on line 44.
```

Why isn't this class found? I've even included two files to make sure, but no go:

```
include ('/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');

include_once( 'classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php' );
```

And I have checked this other question, but mine might be different, thats why I added a new one: [WooCommerce Extending WC_Shipping_Method error: Class 'WC_Shipping_Method' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972184/woocommerce-extending-wc-shipping-method-error-class-wc-shipping-method-not-f)

Comment: It's not about the includes - it's about hooking into the right action and filter hooks ;) - see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstand but:

Your plugin directory name is: `class-wc-shipping-per-product` within `plugins` dir.

So, To include `woocommerce.php` and `abstract-wc-shipping-method.php` (There are within `plugins/woocommerce` directory) you should up one dir and:

**File:** wp-content/plugins/class-wc-shipping-per-product/class-wc-s‌​hipping-per-product.php

```
include_once('../woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
include_once('../woocommerce/classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking through the source code of WooCommerce and various other plugins, this is what I came up with.  In my `shipping-plugin.php` file:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_plugins', 0);
function load_plugins() {
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-custom-shipping.php' );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', array('Custom_Shipping','woocommerce_shipping_methods' ));
```

The key to preventing the class not found error was only including my custom shipping class after the WooCoommerce plugins have been loaded. In my `class-custom-shipping.php` file, I have:

```
class Custom_Shipping extends WC_Shipping_Method {

    public static function woocommerce_shipping_methods( $methods ) {
        $methods[] = 'Custom_Shipping'; return $methods;
    }

    public function __construct() { ... }
    // other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this recently too - various snippets around the web are quite misleading. This is what I've got so far and it seems to work...

```
add_action('woocommerce_shipping_init', 'yourprefix_woocommerce_init_shipping_rate');
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', array('WC_Shipping_XXX_Custom_Rate', 'add_shipping_method'));

function yourprefix_woocommerce_init_shipping_rate()
{

    class WC_Shipping_XXX_Custom_Rate extends WC_Shipping_Method
    {

        static function add_shipping_method($methods)
        {
            $methods[] = 'WC_Shipping_XXX_Custom_Rate';
            return $methods;
        }

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->id = 'yourprefix_custom_shipping';
            $this->method_title = __('yourprefix Custom Shipping', 'woocommerce');
            $this->title = "yourprefix CUSTOM SHIPPING TITLE";  // Displays on the main shipping page
            $this->enabled = true;
            $this->init();
        }

        function init()
        {
            $this->init_settings();
        }

        function is_available($package)
        {
            if ($this->enabled === "no")
                return false;
            return apply_filters('woocommerce_shipping_' . $this->id . '_is_available', true);
        }
```

Comment: I've reported the omissions on the WooCommerce docs page (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/) so hopefully it'll get updated there!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is verbatim from [WooCommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/) and it's broken (!).

I managed to make it work like this:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) )
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_shippin_per_product_method' );

function add_shippin_per_product_method( $methods ) 
{
    // Class definition
    include( 'class-wc-shipping-per-product.php' );
    $methods[] = 'WC_Shipping_Per_Product'; 
    return $methods;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it out.

Comment: Thank you @brasofilo, but that didn't help. I Still get: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Shipping_Method' not found in /var/www/daniel/test/wp-content/plugins/class-wc-shipping-per-product/class-wc-shipping-per-product.php on line 43, referer: http://test.danielholm.se/wp-admin/plugins.php

Latest code: http://pastebin.com/rrhxzaSw